# custom 500 error page in symfony 1.1

Tags: php, symfony1

does symfony redirect to custom error page if Fatal PHP error occurs?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can put the files to here

```
/www/site/web/errors/error500.php
/www/site/web/errors/unavailable.php
```

Read more [19-Mastering-Symfony-s-Configuration-Files](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_1/19-Mastering-Symfony-s-Configuration-Files)

Answer (score 3):

No, you need to set that at the Apache level.

And make sure it's a flat HTML page - if PHP is causing the error and you try to deliver a PHP-driven 500 page, you might get the error again and Apache will figure out that your error page is recurring and display its own anyway.

Example from an .htaccess file

```
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.htm
```